# If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$, is it possible to write $\frac{b-a}{b+a} = \frac{c-d}{c+d}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Consider,
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$$
From this is it possible to write,
$$\frac{b-a}{b+a} = \frac{c-d}{c+d}$$

Edit: It is how to get the second expression from the first

[image]

Comment: This is not true. You either need $b-a$ and $d-c$ in the numerators, or $a-b$ and $c-d$ in the numerators.

Comment: Set $a=c=0$ and $b=d=1$. The first equality is true, but the second becomes $1=-1$.

Answer (score 6):

Divide numerator and denominator of the left hand side by $b$, and of the right hand side by $d$.  Then
$$\frac{b-a}{b+a}=\frac{1-a/b}{1+a/b}=\frac{1-c/d}{1+c/d}=\frac{d-c}{d+c}\ .$$
So, not quite what you asked but almost.  Of course we have to assume that $b$ and $d$ and $b+a$ and $d+c$ are not zero.

Comment: This is not quite what the question asked for, but it is exactly what was **needed**. There is an error in the question; when converting the parts of the complex equations into $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ and $d,$ the expressions for $c$ and $d$ have been mistakenly swapped, leading to a sign error.

Answer (score 1):

I will use determinant to show this. Of course the benefit is that in doing so it will allow you to introduce linear algebra and geometry into understanding the equation that you want to prove in the picture.

Consider the matrix
\begin{align}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Notice that the first condition is equivalent to $\det A = 0$ with $c, d\ne 0$.

By row replacement, we have that
\begin{align}
A\sim \begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
b-a & d-c
\end{bmatrix}
\sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{b+a}{2} & \frac{c+d}{2}\\
b-a & d-c
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Since row replacement doesn't change the determinant, then it follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{b+a}{2}(d-c) = \frac{c+d}{2}(b-a).
\end{align}
This yields the desired result.